# Explanation of GetNormalizedUserNameAsync and SetNormalizedUserNameAsync functions in ASP.NET Identity UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am a bit confused as to how I am supposed to implement functions like the following:

```
GetNormalizedRoleNameAsync(TRole, CancellationToken)
SetNormalizedRoleNameAsync(TRole, String, CancellationToken)
GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(TUser, CancellationToken)
SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(TUser, String, CancellationToken)
GetUserNameAsync(TUser, CancellationToken)
SetUserNameAsync(TUser, String, CancellationToken)
```

**In the ASP.NET Core CustomIdentityProvider Sample and the Actual ASP.NET Core Identity UserStoreBase class they do the following:**

```
public Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    if (normalizedName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(normalizedName));

    user.NormalizedUserName = normalizedName;
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

    return Task.FromResult(user.UserName);
}
```

Are these functions about just simply extracting the Normalized Name from an already populated User object and additionally updating the Normalized Name on an already populated User object. I am not seeing the purpose of these functions can someone explain?

Also do I need to actually persist the NormalizedUserName and NormalizedRoleName in my custom User/Role tables or are they not required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer can be found in the way the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` lookup users / roles. Since they both work similarly, I'll focus on the `UserManager`.

When calling [`UserManager.FindByNameAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c95ee2b051814b787b07f55ff224d03d550aafeb/src/Identity/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L543), the `UserManager` first normalize the key before passing it to your `UserStore`:

```
public virtual async Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    userName = NormalizeKey(userName);
    var user = await Store.FindByNameAsync(userName, CancellationToken);
    return user;    
}
```

where

```
// injected via dependency injection
ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer; 

public virtual string NormalizeKey(string key)
{
    return (KeyNormalizer == null) ? key : KeyNormalizer.Normalize(key);
}
```

The goal is probably to ensure that no matter the input, the DB request always uses a consistent key.

Note that Identity framework actually uses `UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer` by default (via [`IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c95ee2b051814b787b07f55ff224d03d550aafeb/src/Identity/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38)).

That means that when you implement `IUserStore<User>.FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`, `normalizedUserName` is not the string you passed to the `UserManager` method, but its upper case version.

So to finally answer your questions:

- `GetNormalizedUserNameAsync` isn't used anywhere in the Identity framework.
- `SetNormalizedUserNameAsync` is used during creation / update of a user, and is called with the upper case version of your user name. You don't *need* to persist it, but it might be preferable, since the User lookup is based on the normalized version.
- `GetUserNameAsync` the string that will be normalized before calling `GetNormalizedUserNameAsync`. Not used anywhere else in the Identity framework.

Final note: you can change the `ILookupNormalizer` by adding a scoped service before calling `AddIdentity`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
    services
        .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore>();
}
```